# SQL trigger, results not Grouped by

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger with query, and the results should be grouped by TransportID. But when trigger executes and writes records in Table2, they are not grouped. And ideas?

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trigger]    Script Date: 16. 08. 2019 10:50:47 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT into Table2(TransportID,Ta2O5)
SELECT

   [TransportID],
round(sum([Ta2O5]/100*[Weight])/sum([Weight])*100,2) as Ta2O5

  FROM inserted  
  GROUP BY
       TransportID
END
```

Data inserted into table 1:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ([ID],[TransportID],[Weight],[Ta2O5]) VALUES (1,200000016,36.5,4.1),(2,200000016,34,4.4);
```

Expected output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT9n4.png)

Comment: Don't you think `SUM()` must be the outer? eg: `SUM(ROUND(....))`

Comment: that is because `Round` is not a grouping function. You need to have `Sum` as first for your `Ta205` column formula

Comment: some sample input and expected output data will be helpful

Comment: In another way to make you understand better `ROUND()` is not an [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: what about `Weight` column, check your formula once again to calculate your value.

Comment: @DarkRob Sorry forgot to add Weight column to my edit.

Comment: This isn’t exactly a solution, but I recommend to keep business logic outside of triggers if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the trigger write by you, you are calculating on `inserted`, which contains always single row inserted.

For example when your first insertion is performed with values
 `INSERT INTO Table1 ([ID],[TransportID],[Weight],[Ta2O5]) VALUES (1,200000016,36.5,4.1)`

At this point of time your trigger will be called for this particular value, and that is always returning 1 row in your inserted. Which makes no sense of doing `sum` of values since there are only one row.
As per your formula which calculates as :`round( (1.3 / 100 * 36.5 ) / 36.5 * 100, 2)` which give you `1.30000000000`.

So I think you need to update your trigger to first insert then update on your insertion as.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    if exists (select * from table2 where TransportID in ( select   inserted.TransportID from inserted))
    Begin
        update t2 set t2.ta205 = t.ta205 from table2 as t2 inner join 
        (       
            SELECT
               [TransportID],
                round(sum([Ta2O5] /100 * [Weight] ) /sum( [Weight] ) * 100 ,2) as Ta2O5
              FROM Table1  
              where TransportID in (select inserted.TransportID from inserted)
              GROUP BY  TransportID
        ) as t on t.TransportID = t2.TransportID
    End
    else
    Begin
        INSERT into Table2(TransportID,Ta2O5)
        SELECT
           [TransportID], 
           round( sum([Ta2O5] /100 * [Weight] ) / sum( [Weight] ) * 100 ,2) as Ta2O5 
          FROM Table1  
          where TransportID in (select inserted.TransportID from inserted)
          GROUP BY  TransportID
    End
END
```

Comment: I get: The multi-part identifier "inserted.TransportID" could not be bound. That is for first "inserted.TransportID".

Comment: I get no errors and the trigger seems to be working as i wanted it. Thanks :)

Comment: If I would have more then 1 column for calculating in select statement. How would I add this columns to the "update" part?

Comment: "inserted, which contains always single row inserted." - This is 100% incorrect. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. If you insert statement insert 10 rows then the inserted virtual table will have 10 rows.

Comment: And the inserted table might have zero rows too! Be careful what you assume.